# How to test Retrofit2 + RxJava2 api call?

Tags: android, api, unit-testing, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am wondering how to test Retrofit2 call via rxjava2. My retrofit api interface looks like:

```
public interface LoginApiMapping {
   @POST("v1/secm/oam/oauth2/token")
   Observable<Response<RestResponseHolder<LoginResponseModel>>> login(@Body LoginModel model);
}
```

and i would like to write the test which will send this request via RxJava2 and check the response. I consider that there is the problem with RxJava as it is asynchronous and the test finishes before i get the response, so i tried to use TestSubscriber as below, but it's not possible to subscribe TestSubscriber<Response<RestResponseHolder<LoginResponseModel>>> as i expected

```
@Test
public void loginTest(){
    Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    Api t = TestApi.create(appContext);
    LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel("username","password");
    TestSubscriber<Response<RestResponseHolder<LoginResponseModel>>> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    t.get(LoginApiMapping.class).login(loginModel).subscribe(testSubscriber);
}
```

anyone who solved that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution, so i decided to post it here.
First you have to call toFlowable() on the observable and set the Backpressure strategy and then you can subscribe with TestSubscriber as below

```
t.get(LoginApiMapping.class).login(loginModel).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP).subscribe(testSubscriber);
```

Then add

```
testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
```

at the end that you can check various assertions on testSubscriber as R. Zagórski pointed in answer above.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of of test add:

```
testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
```

Then you can check various assertions on `testSubscriber`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, i think it will be useful, but first i need to be able to subscribe the TestSubscriber<Response<RestResponseHolder<LoginResponseModel>>> what is not possible. Maybe it might have some problems with genericity? In this example it seems working http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2015/09/13/testing-rxjava-observables-subscriptions/ with object RubberChicken. Maybe its becouse of RxJava2? I cannot even compile it when i try to subscribe my object.

Answer (score 0):

You use TestSubscriber with Flowable and TestObserver with Observable. You can test Single, Completable and Maybe by converting them to either Flowable or Observable, but the built-in test()s for these three return TestSubscriber.